# React - changing input value from a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Alrighty, so I'm using some color picker that changes my this.state.colorPicked and that works fine, now I have an input field I'd like to write a function that I can call that would concat the value of my state colorPicked if it was empty, or concat comma and that value if it was not, how can I access this input field?
 I'm using react-bootstrap

[image]

```js
            <InputGroup className="mb-3">
              <FormControl
                name="color"
                onChange={this.change}
                placeholder="Available Colors"
                aria-label="Available Colors"
              />
            </InputGroup>
            <div style={{ display: "flex", "flex-direction": "row" }}>
              <TwitterPicker
                className="mb-3"
                onChange={this.handleColorChange}
              />
              <Button
                style={{
                  background: this.state.colorPicked
                }}
                onClick={() => this.addColor(this.state.colorPicked)}
              >
                Add Color!
              </Button>
            </div>
```

TIA

Clarification: I want to pick the color, the onchange detector sets it to the state and hence the button's background, now on button click I want to add it's hex (the state) to the text field as text input, if input is not empty I would precede that with a comma.

Comment: Well you've gone as far as writing a change handler, what does it look like? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep an array of colors?

Comment: @James 7 Im not sure how to access the text field,

Comment: @Henry Woody, pretty much yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With react forms we use 2 way binding from state, onChange and value attributes.
First add the value attribute and set it to state property for ex inputField.

```
<FormControl
   name="color"
   onChange={this.change}
   placeholder="Available Colors"
   aria-label="Available Colors"
   value=={this.state.inputField}
   />
```

Now you can write a logic inside your change function.. something like

```
change = (e)=>{

 this.setState({inputField:e.target.value}
 // then copy array from state
 let arrFromState = [...this.state.colorPicked]
 let updatedArray = [...arrFromState, this.state.inputField] 
 // or use concat, push etc
 this.setState({colorPicked:updatedArray})



}
```

I didn't understood the exact thing you wanted to do.
But thats the basic approach while working with react forms. Two way binding

Comment: Works perfect, the binding also had the ability to manual edit the text field disable, thanks.

Comment:  It was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

To access input value you can use onChange method on your input, pass it an event and access it through `event.target.value`. It should look similar to this:

`<input onChange={(event) => logInputValue(event)}`

`const logInputValue = ({ event: { target: { value } = {} } }) => { console.log(value) }`

Comment: I don't think you understood my issue, the form I put the code for is where I want to INPUT the string, the string being in my `this.state.colorPicked`

Comment: so what you want is to pass value from this.state.colorPicked to <FormControl> ? Could you show us implementation of FormControl component? You could simply go with passing props like <FormControl colorPicker={this.state.colorPicker} />

Comment: What implementation do you want me to show? literally the only code relating to it is in the question, is there something else I should add?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to pass this.state.colorPicker value to FormControl component and then changing it using onChange method? Could you please clarify it?

Comment: Ive updated the clarification, code, and added a screenshot.

Comment: Alright, so what you want here is the implementation of addColor function which takes one parameter and sets input field value to in example - orange, #fe0000 ?

Comment: exactly, as you can see in the code it can just take the state, now that I have it, inside that function how can i set the input field's value to it? (Or better yet, concat it to the value in the input field)

Comment: why does it have to be input field? Should user be able to change its value?

Comment: It's actually better if they cannot, but I don't know what that would be? some sort of textview? im open to suggestions.

Comment: like yeah they shouldn't be able to change it's value, except through the color picker and clicking add color

Comment: Oh but like they should have a way to remove such elements from it, I'm basically doing this to end up with an array of colors chosen by the user, like ["#ffffff,#fe1221,#ff0012], an implementation that comes to mind is material chips in android but idk if that is possible here.